# Laravel: How to get foreign key and pass it to controller

Tags: php, html, laravel, model, key

I'm trying to get a the `id` from the `category table` which is the `foreign key` in the `article table` and placing it in a `hidden` field in a view when creating an article, I then want to pass it to the `article controller`, i've had a go at trying but unsure how to do this. The error that is displaying is

> Too few arguments to function
>   App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::create(), 0 passed and exactly
>   1 expected

Comment: passing to article Controller means??

Comment: please edit your post and show your article and category migrations

Comment: I'm creating a article so need to pass it the article controller to store the article

Comment: show your migrations too

Comment: The problem is that Laravel is not passing an `$id` to `ArticleController::create()`. You are probably missing a parameter in your route configuration. Can you post the `ArticleController` routes?

Comment: I've included my routes and also my category store method as i think this has a part in passing over the $id

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass anything in create method, instead display dropdown list of category in your article view so that you can select any category, then get Category id from that dropdown to your store method.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Category;


class ArticleController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function index()
{
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
  $categories = Category::pluck('title', 'id')
  return view('article.create', ['categories' => $categories]);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $input = $request->all();
  Article::create($input);
  return redirect('article');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{

}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{

}

}
```

And in your View

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'ArticleController@store', 'id' => 'createArticle')) !!}
@csrf


    <div class="row large-12 columns">
         {!! Form::label('', 'Category:') !!}
         {!! Form::select('category_id', $categories, null, ) !!}

        {!! Form::label('', 'Title:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'large-8 columns']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: thank you very much it worked!!! Is there any other way to do this as a have i foreign keys in other tables that i need to place in a form hidden and i don't think maybe that method may work for them.

Comment: Of course you can do it. But in that case you need to pass category id everytime to your create function explicitly. For example you need to create a new article, but you have to specify for which category you are going to create the article. For that show a list of category in one page and then give hyperlink to create method of your article, passing category_id as parameter. <a href="{url('article/create)}.'/'.{$category_id}". That $category_id will be dynamic for each category.